# Configure self hosted Web api to share port 80

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have written a self hosted asp.net Web-API application which will serve on port 80. This is a restriction of the closed network it will be deployed on.

The application works fine, however suddenly during testing the service refused to start throwing the following error.

```
 HTTP could not register URL http://+:80/ because TCP port 80 is being
 used by another application.
```

Indeed we found that Skype had been started on that test machine and was listening on port 80. Killing Skype resolved the situation. However when deployed, we cannot guarantee our application will have port 80 to itself.

Therefore my question to is: 
**Is it possible to configure self hosted WebApi to share listening on port 80?**

Comment: Why would anything want to listen on port 80 except a proper HTTP server? (and no, you can't "share" a port)

Comment: A fair statement, I guess Skype were trying to get around potential firewall issues. As for the "port sharing", you are of course correct. The question came about because of this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734772.aspx. Which is a WCF feature of which Web API is built on.
Thank you Jon for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 2):

After some bit-mining, its pretty easy to fix this issue if you go to `%appdata%\Skype\shared.xml` and edit `config\Lib\Connection\DisablePort80` to 1 and then reboot Skype, it will be fixed :)

I can't share the XML but here is it stripped:

```
<config timestamp="1365161986.70" serial="11206" version="1.0">
   <Lib>
      <DisablePort80>1</DisablePort80>
   </Lib>
</config>
```